# Synchronous-like behavior in XHR without using async flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

As most know, XHR has a flag that allows users to specify async/sync requests in `open`.

I have a JSON list of request items. I have a React state array called `history` that displays a list of every request made to the user.

My React component hierarchy is as follows

`App -> HttpRequest -> RequestAutomate`

Currently, everything works like this

```
<RequestAutomate Component>
for each request in JSON list:
    this.props.submit(request)

<HttpRequest Component>
submit(request)
    xhr.open(request.verb, request.url, false) // note async set to false
    set the body and header with request.body and request.header
    xhr.send
    callback if xhr.readyState === 4
        this.props.addHistory(request object that was made)

<App component>
addHistory(request)
    // add to history state array.
```

React usually rerenders every time a state is modified. Since each request that is sent into `submit` is added into the `history` array when (and only when) it is ready, I want my program to rerender so that users can see their requests being added one by one.

However, when XHR is set to synchronous mode, the UI is blocked from rerendering (please correct me if I am wrong & sound like an idiot here). Therefore, the UI will just rerender itself with the entire request history at the same time. If I have 30 requests in my request JSON, the UI will rerender and display all 30 at the same time. I want them to display out one at a time, as they're being run. Is there a way to do this functionality with XHR in async mode with some kind of combination of callbacks (or whatever solution someone is able to come up with)

Edit: I should note the reason why I am using synchronous requests. Requests must be run in sequential order as they come in, since there is a possibility that a request depends on one before it (ie. request 5 could depend on request 1). As a result, I want every request to be finished before the next one runs

Comment: look at using `fetch` instead, and learn how to use Promise chaining .... or for asynchronous code that *"looks synchronous"* - `async`/`await` (with fetch, because fetch uses Promises, which is what async/await uses)

Comment: Cool, I was able to get it to work the way I wanted to with `fetch` along with `async`/`await`. Thanks!